# ExtJS 4 - Load Mask giving errors in IE8 and IE9 when used while opening a window

Tags: extjs, load, window, extjs4, mask

I have a window which opens up on a button click. The window takes time to load and hence I am using load mask in following way:

```
handler:function(){
    var myMask      =       new Ext.LoadMask(Ext.getBody(), {msg:"Loading..."});
    myMask.show();
    var winAppln    =       showWin(myMask);
    if(winAppln){
        var task = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function(){
            winAppln.show();
        });
        task.delay(2000);
    }
}
```

I am hiding the mask object in the afterrender function of window in following way:

```
afterrender:function(){
    if(maskObj){
        maskObj.hide();
    }
}
```

The above code works fine in all the browsers, except IE (version 9 and 8).

In IE9 and IE8, there is an error generated as "Invalid Argument" in ext-all-debug.js at line 8682 which is as following

```
me.dom.style[ELEMENT.normalize(style)] = value;
```

Could anyone guide that what can be a possible reason behind this.

Also, my main purpose is to cover the lag between the click of button & opening of window, so that user is aware about something is happening. Is there a better way of doing this other then using Load Mask, or could Load Mask be used in some different manner, then as shown above?

Thanks in advance.

PS: I am using ExtJS Version 4.0.7

Comment: Investigating the things, I found that the property - modal:true, used by me in the window is having a clash with the loadMask. If I remove this property then things work fine in IE too. But, using modal:true is a necessity for me as per the functionality. Any idea on this anyone that how could this be resolved?

Comment: I have been able to locate a workaround for this by giving this.modal:true in the afterrender function of the window after hiding the load mask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the things found by me so far, this issue is caused when the window has modal:true set.

IE 8 and 9 create a conflict between loadMask and modal:true and throw an error.

A workaround for this is to take off modal:true from the window and set it to true in the afterrender event of window once the loadmask hide function has been called as below:

```
afterrender:function(){
    if(maskObj){
        maskObj.hide();
    }
    this.modal = true;
}
```

Hope this helps someone looking for the same.

Comment: might be worth reporting to Sencha as a bug

Comment: yeah Jaitsu, I shall be posting this as a bug there. Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in ExtJS4 Ext.LoadMask which is a problem in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.

When showing a loading mask, ExtJs tries to figure out the zIndex of the parent element, then setting the zIndex of the loading mask. In Internet Explorer 7/8 an element could also have set the zIndex "auto". parseInt of the string "auto" is NaN. Setting the zIndex to NaN causes an error in IE7/IE8.

The solution: override LoadMask

```
Ext.override(Ext.LoadMask, {
    setZIndex: function(index) {
        var me = this, 
            owner = me.activeOwner;

        if (owner) {
            index = parseInt(owner.el.getStyle('zIndex'), 10) + 1;
        }
        if (!isNaN(index)) {
            me.getMaskEl().setStyle('zIndex', index - 1);
            return me.mixins.floating.setZIndex.apply(me, arguments);
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
});
```

This topic is discussed also in Sencha Forums:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228673-LoadMask-and-setZIndex-and-NaN
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?246839

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try with

```
Ext.getBody().mask("Loading")
```

I use this instead of LoadMask just because in ext you can't mask more than one component with dimmed background color, .mask() does the trick. LoadMask is prettier, but has some issues, so .mask could work.

Comment: Thanks for the post Exter. I tried by using mask function on body. This did generate a loading message but did not mask the elements, that is, even when the loading message is appearing, the users are able to click around at the other elements present, which is not what is expected. Any workaround for this? Thanks again.